# How to fix this incrementation?

Tags: c++

I am trying to increment the number of slashes per the user input, but cannot seem to get it to work.

So far, I have:

```
int numberOfDolls = 0;
    cout << "Number of dolls -> ";
    cin >> numberOfDolls;

     
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++)
        cout << '/' << endl;
      
      cout << "-" << endl;
    }
```

and if the user enters 3, it prints:

```
/
/
/
-
/
/
/
-
/
/
/
-
```

it should read:

```
/
-
/
/
-
/
/
/
-
```

Can anyone get me started in the right direction?

Comment: Why should it be what you suggested?

Comment: Your second loop should not be `for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++)` , it should be `for (int k = i; k <= i; k++)` You mixed two loop indexes with the same variable. I'm not sure why you didn't get compiler's warning/error

Comment: consider using a different variable name than `i`. You declared it twice in the same scope. I'm surprised you didn't get warnings or possibly an error from doing this

Comment: Why would int k = i? Isn't k going to be the '/' we need to print? That prints numbers rather than slashes @LouisGo

Comment: The point of this is to look for patterns that correspond to loops. There are two loops, and two patterns. Look again.

Comment: @wockywoad it should be `k=1`, my mistake.

Comment: Also I found gcc 11 doesn't complain about duplicate index variable..

Comment: @LouisGo, The warning you're looking for is `-Wshadow`. It's one of the ones not included in `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Comment: More idiomatic in C++ to have `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDolls; ++i)` than `for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you have are two identical loops that will output `n` groups of `n` slashes. If you want to display an incrementing number, you do need two loops, but they have to have different maximum values. Your first loop is correct, but the second (that outputs the characters) needs to be based off of the first loop. If you use the outside loop as the maximum number of characters to display, the inside loop will be this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
    ...
```